# How to use soap request in krakenD

Tags: gitkraken, krakend

I'm not going to use the enterprise version of krakenD gateway. May I know how can I use soap request in krakenD.

Pls help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP integration feature is exclusive to the KrakenD Enterprise version. It allows for handling multiple encodings, such as XML or JSON, and transforming them before returning the content to the user. Additionally, it enables crafting the body and XML content sent to a SOAP service by injecting dynamic variables from the user body, headers, query strings, or URL parameters​.

This feature also provides the capacity to manipulate responses to achieve the desired output, irrespective of the end user's encoding or method. It introduces templates to craft the body sent as an underlying SOAP XML contract to the server while keeping this complexity hidden from the end user. You can choose to keep the SOAP response modified or "as is," return JSON content or another encoding​. You can read the complete SOAP integration docs at https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/backends/soap/

Since you're not using the Enterprise version, this feature might not be accessible to you. However, if SOAP integration is crucial for your application, KrakenD offers trial Enterprise licenses. You might want to try this feature before making a decision. To request a trial license, you can send a request from the following page: [KrakenD Enterprise Contact Sales](https://www.krakend.io/enterprise/#contact-sales). It's also worth considering upgrading to the Enterprise version if SOAP integration becomes a significant requirement for your application.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post link-only answers but summarize the linked content or its relevant parts a little. A link may become invalid or outdated and in that case, your answer would be useless in the future. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Comment: Thanks for noticing @ahuemmer! I've just edited my answer accordingly.